# Xamarin Can't Run iOS App on iPhone Simulator - no support for 386 architecture

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, simulator

I'm using Visual Studio Mac 2017 and attempting to run an app on the iPhone simulator, but the **Run** button is showing a small "hammer" icon (instead of the usual "play" icon)

Also, all options under the Run menu are greyed out (e.g. Start Without Debugging, Start Debugging, etc)

My conclusion is that it's because the simulator requires 386 architecture but this is not listed as a supported architecture: **option > iOS Build > Supported Architectures**

I've tried adjusting the SDK, Deployment Target, and  Minimum System Version, but unable to see 386 as an architecture option or show the Run button.

I reckon I'm missing something really simple here, but I can't figure out what. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the current **Platform** from `iPhone` to `iPhoneSimulator`

Once `iPhoneSimulator` is chosen, the "Supported architectures" will change to `x86_64` (also with an option for `x86` for older versions of Xamarin.iOS)

[image]

Comment: omg that's embarrassingly simple. I won't tell you how many hours (days) I've spent trying to resolve this. Cheers SushiHangover!!

Comment: @RumbleFish NP ;-) We have all been there, and done that 